# What are the advantages of LePUS3 over UML?

Tags: uml, modeling

When searching online for object oriented concepts such as [the composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) I often found them represented in the LePUS3 notation. I am not really familiar with this 
modeling language.

Is it something I should prefer over UML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LePUS3 was designed to be an improvement over other modeling languages and is specifically designed to be an enhancement to UML. The benefits of LePUS3 are laid out in [the paper that introduced it](http://www.springerlink.com/content/w74v6u527234031q/), and you can see a summary of these benefits on the preview of the scientific paper show at the link.

I'll reproduce the paper's stated advantages here:

- **Rigour.** LePUS3 is a logic visual language: a chart stands for a formula in an axiomatized theory in the classical first-order predicate calculus.
- **Parsimony & scalability.** LePUS3 offers powerful abstractions: charts scale well and do not clutter with the size of the program.
- **Minimality.** LePUS3 vocabulary is minimal, consisting of 15 tokens.
- **Decidability & verifiability.** Consistency between a given specification (a chart) and an implementation (a Java program) can be verified by a button-click.
- **Program Visualization.** Charts modeling Java programs can be reverse-engineered from source code.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can reverse-engineer LePUS3 charts from source code and get meaningful results
2. LePUS3 is a formal language
3. You can model programs of any size in LePUS3
4. You can model design patters in LePUS3 not as programs but as generic design motifs

Answer (score 0):

I would say that apart from other good features of LePus3, mentioned by the other answers, there is one more, extremely important from my point of view:

In UML you can make a plan of SW
In LePus3 you can make a plan, or a plan of the plan, or a plan of the plan of the plan, or even the common plan for several levels of abstraction.

The LePus3 is the only diagram language that is formalized and simultaneously adapted for metathinking.

On the other hand, using of LePus3 requires very much greater intellect. The level difference between them is great. If you are a good user of UML, that does mean you can use LePus3. It is pity that there are no instruments between them.

**And yes, I love LePus3!**